# What is the best way to model an organization using people, positions and teams when people have multiple jobs?

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, modeling, orgchart

I have an interesting modeling problem.  I am trying generate an org chart on a website (the backend is C# / SQL server and the frontend is javascript / google orgchart API, but the crux of the modeling problem is more generic so I didn't include any of the specific technologies in the tags below as the issue is not around any tech specific issues.

I have the following 4 database tables:

1. **Team** - which has fields Id, Name, ParentTeamId (which is another row in the same table)
2. **Position** - which represents a position within a team.  Fields are Id, TeamId, IsTeamHead, etc
3. **Person** - represents a person (no linkage in this table to any other table). Fields are Id, FirstName, LastName, etc
4. **PersonPosition** - represent people in positions (this bridges the two tables) Fields are Id, PersonId, PositionId, StartDate, EndDate

When I have a plain vanilla org chart this works perfectly because i basically loop through each **Team** (since each has its **ParentTeamId**) and build up a team hierarchy and show the **position** in that team (using the **TeamId** field) with "Ishead" = true and show the person that is associated with that position as the head.

My issue is that (as not so uncommon), there are people that now have been given multiple responsibilities - they essentially have 2 different jobs.  Previously, Joe was head of marketing and Bill was regional head but Joe left

Before the head of marketing and the regional head, which was 2 different **people** (2 different **positions**)   So Bill is the head of Marketing but is also regional manager in the US.  I am trying to figure out what is the correct way to model and visualize this.

The first part of the modeling problem is to decide if I should model this as two different **positions**.  If I do, i can have multiple entries in this **PersonPosition** table (both with the same **PersonId**) but the issue there is that it feels like I am overcounting number of positions.

Also, from a visualization point of view, the same person would show up in 2 places.  Maybe that is correct from a functional point of view but seems odd that you would have the same person listed multiple times (maybe its not so odd but wanted to get feedback on what people have seen in this case as the expected visualization and what seems acceptable maybe should drive the modeling)

Any suggestions for the "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 12):

Looks like you need something similar to this:

[image]

Out of all the possible position "types" (`Position`) we build a set of positions that exist in the specific team (`TeamPosition`) and identify the person that fills each position (`TeamPosition.PersonId`<sup>1</sup>).

The head is represented by the "reverse" foreign key FK2 in `Team`<sup>2</sup>. Unlike a boolean flag, this naturally ensures there cannot be more than one head position per team.

This model also allows different teams to be headed by different types of positions: for example one team might be headed by a "head of marketing" while the other is headed by a "senior technical officer".

It is still possible to have the same person fulfill multiple positions (including head positions), which is compatible with your requirements, as far as I understand. And if that's true, then I don't really see a problem in showing the same person as a member of multiple teams in the UI. Alternatively, you could designate one of the person's position's as "primary" (using a "reverse" FK similar to above) and then just show the primary position and a "More..." button  beside it (or similar).

---

*<sup>1</sup> Make it NOT NULL if there cannot be a vacant team position. If the same position can exist multiple times per team, either move the `PersonId` to `TeamPosition` PK, or add a new field `PositionNo` to the PK. If the same person cannot have multiple positions inside the same team, add an alternate key on `{TeamId, PersonId}`.*

*<sup>2</sup> Unfortunately, MS SQL Server is a bit more squeamish than some other DBMSes, and will refuse to do referential actions (such as ON DELETE CASCADE) on circular references like this. If you need referential actions, implement them via INSTEAD OF triggers.*

Comment: No activity on this question for two days, and then two answers within a minute...

Comment: @Branko - i like the idea of a positionteam table as that provide flexibility because at one point a position is in mulitple teams and that may change over time.  The one question i have is 99% of positions will only have one team . . is there anyway that you can think of where i can only manage the ones with more than one (instead of having to maintain info for the other 99% in that table

Comment: @leore If you are absolutely positive this will continue to be the case as your database grows, then keep your old model and repeat positions in few necessary places (alternatively, I can see how a "hybrid" between your old model and mine could look like, but that would complicate querying). However, this all looks a bit unusual to me... I don't know which industry you are trying to model, but in IT at least, there are many positions that repeat, such as "junior developer", "senior developer" or "team leader". Many of these positions repeat not just between teams but within the same team.

Comment: @Branko - position in my case is not a description of a role or level of seniority.  Its just represents a headcount that may or may not be filled with a person.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should consider the difference between a "position" and a "role". In many organizations, multiple roles may exist: safety coordinator, purchasing, accounts payable, receptionist, ... Often, especially in smaller organizations, a single person may act in different roles at different times. It may even be that they report to different people when they act in different capacities (for example, the emergency responder may report to the safety coordinator, but the purchaser reports to head of operations.)

In order to properly reflect these things, the relationships in your database need to reflect, to the extent possible, the relationships that exist in real life. This probably means you will have multiple tables (as you already have), but it will keep things clean.

The other thing to keep in mind (and possibly worth reflecting in your database) is that many organizations are *matrixed*: people may be on certain *project teams*, and part of certain *organizations*. The electrical engineers may all report to the electrical engineering manager, but they might be working on different projects / products, and thus belong on different project teams.

Capturing all that accurately is hard. Here is my suggestion (not unlike yours, but with some tweaks):

**Table 1: employees** Person name, Employee ID, Start Date, Salary, Vacation, ...
This is the table that says when you get paid, how much vacation time you have, what your "HR status" is. There is only one of you - this table has only one of you, and is used for those things which can't be doubled up (although we'd all like two pay checks).

**Table 2: managers** Manager ID, Report ID, Report kind
This table states, for each manager, who are the people reporting to them, and what kind of relationship it is. You might have a "primary" relationship, and other relationships: "project leader", "team leader", ... The "primary" manager might make HR type decisions, with inputs from "other" managers.

**Table 3: teams** Team name, Team ID, Manager ID, BelongsToTeam, Team description, ...
A table that describes every "organizational entity", with any auxiliary information that might be useful. The BelongsToTeam allows a hierarchical structure of teams, which helps with visualization.

**Table 4: roles** Role name, Team ID, Employee ID, isPrimary
This table describes who is in a given role. An employee with multiple roles will show up multiple times in this table, and may report to different managers depending on the role they have. I added an "isPrimary" field here - not sure if that is redundant. In a sense, if you start with the "primary" role of the employee in table 4, and find out who the team manager is in table 3, you should end up with the person in table 2 who is the primary manager... I worry that you might end up with inconsistency if you leave this in both places.

I believe the above allows you to describe almost any organization - by allowing the "isPrimary" field in table 4, it would even be possible that the same person who is your "HR boss" over all shows up as your "project leader" in a second team, and might even be reporting to you on the emergency response team...

As for visualization - there are two obvious ways to do this with the above structure. The first is "strictly hierarchical" - only showing people underneath their primary manager. This is the "HR org chart", and everyone shows up only once.

You can have a second chart which is "team based". Now, every team has its own organization, and the same person can show up in multiple teams. How these teams relate to each other can be tricky - but in principle, table 3 should provide what you need with the BelongsToTeam field.

I look forward to hearing your thoughts on this!

Comment: Your statement "there's a difference between a position and a role" is CRITICAL. As you say, but I will repeat 'cos it's so important, management/reporting hierarchy is not related to teams at all (whether or not the management style is officially matrixed). Many cross-functional teams are comprised from people from people selected from all over an organisation. Indeed a more junior employee might head a team with a more senior staff member as 'merely' a team member. This leads to a slight improvement: you also need Organisation as a separate table to model departments and lines-of-business.

Comment: @Floris - i am curious of your opinion around using a PositionTeam table  (as Branko suggests) to achieve this idea that a single position can be a different "role" in multiple teams

Comment: I think it is better to show the direct link from employee to team (or composition of team in terms of employees) rather than from position; multiple people may have the same position (title). The exception would be where someone is part of a team _ex officio_ - but those situations don't really need their own table.

Comment: @Floris - the issue with having employee to team is that if a person leaves, there is no good way of showing that there is an open "position" there .. I am using position in maybe a slightly different way than you think.  I use it just to represent a holding spot on a team.  A position and a person are linked through an allocation table.  so i can look at a position and see the different people who have been mapped to it over time.  Also, we have cases of co heads so PositionTeam having a IsHead field seems to allow more flexibility of position in multiple teams and supporting coheads

Comment: @leora - all of us giving inputs do so based on our own experience and our understanding of your requirements. In the end you take our inputs (you have no way of knowing our qualifications) , make your own design decisions, and live with them. If anything I wrote was helpful, I'm glad. Your tweaks make sense for the needs you describe.

Comment: In our org we have used "dummy employees" as a way of showing open positions - they are just like regular employees but have an "open" flag and a unique employee ID. This allows you to describe the opening in the same structure. Again - may not work for you.

Comment: The dummy employee may seem like a hack - until you think of them as "the employee I haven't hired yet". Once they are on board, they already have an employee ID number and everything. Just just update some information (hiring date, name, etc) - and you're done. They are already "in the system". But your solution works too. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As you say, it's commonly for staff to (formally or informally) fulfil more than one role within an organisation. However, as far as HR/payroll/other admin depts are concerned an employee will only officially hold one position. It's important to presrve this to ensure that people aren't paid twice or otherwise over/under compensated etc.

You can enforce this by adding `hr/admin_position` column to the `person` table. The `person_position` table can then be used to record all the roles they actually do.

This also allows people to be assigned an "org chart" position that's different to the one HR believes they perform. This can often happen when a team leader leaves; a junior member of the team will be "promoted" to interim team lead, taking on the extra responsibilities. However, no corresponding increase in salary or other benefits has taken place, because HR still considers them to be doing the more junior position. You could add extra columns to include notes or flags to indicate these are temporary positions.

Comment: I don't need to make person_id nullable, if there is a position with no person then i don't need a record in the PersonPosition table at all . .when a person comes on board, a record in personPosition will be created . .

Comment: @leora - good point, you don't need it. I've removed that part

Answer (score 1):

"The first part of the modeling problem is to decide if I should model this as two different positions. If I do, i can have multiple entries in this PersonPosition table (both with the same PersonId) but the issue there is that it feels like I am overcounting number of positions."

No there is no issue.  The issue you mention is that if anyone wants to "count number of positions", but accesses the personposition table to do so, makes a mistake.  Out of not understanding the database, or the data model, or whatever, thing is : if what one needs is to count number of positions, one needs to access the positions table.

"Also, from a visualization point of view,"

Just a sidenote here that if "visualisation" is your actual problem, database people are typically not the ones to help you.

"the same person would show up in 2 places. Maybe that is correct from a functional point of view"

If it's the business rule then it's the business rule.  It is typically not up to you to question them.  What if different people share the same single position ?  E.g. two part-timers each doing [their half of] the very same job.

"but seems odd that you would have the same person listed multiple times (maybe its not so odd but wanted to get feedback on what people have seen in this case as the expected visualization and what seems acceptable maybe should drive the modeling)."

Well you've just said it.  If it's the business rule then it's not odd.  Maybe you've never encountered such a scenario before, but who cares about that ?

"Any suggestions for the "right" way to do this?"

Not really.  All you need to do is figure out what information *precisely* is to be rendered.  All the existing positions, with an empty name if they're currently not occupied ?  Only the effectively occupied positions, with any single name of the possibly multiple persons occupying that position ?  etc. etc.

Comment: i definately need to show open positions (which i do and which is why i show positions and not people).  I just never had a situation where one person had 2 different jobs so trying to figure out if i need to refactor my database design or not ..  . .

Comment: `Just a sidenote here that if "visualisation" is your actual problem, database people are typically not the ones to help you.` - got a good chuckle from that!

Comment: I was talking of techniques for visualization of the content, not of the structure !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Leora, The database design as given (i.e. without any specified constraint) supports one person having different jobs, as well as "one job having different persons".  No refactoring will be needed merely because either of those possibilities must be supported, as they already are.